# UFD in Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

> Prove that $$\frac{\mathbb Z[x,y]}{\left<y+1\right>}$$ is a unique factorization domain.

I think (intuition) it is isomorphic to $Z[x]$ but i am unable to prove, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Consider the map $\mathbf{Z}[x,y] \to \mathbf{Z}[x]$ defined by $f(x, y) \mapsto f(x, -1)$. What's its kernel?